# Why do Rebecca's breasts appear polished/shiny?

Tags: one-piece

I don't understand this image:

[image]

If you look at her headgear, you'll see that it's polished and has that clean shine. But what's up with her breasts? They appear to be *shining* or they look polished, just like her helmet. I don't watch One Piece. So I don't know if she has shiny breasts, or if she polishes them. Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: That's just smooth skin

Comment: Or a lot of baby oil... clearly you haven't been watching enough body building shows.

Comment: Best I can do: http://fitfreely.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/lisa-aukland.jpg

Comment: None.  It's conjecture and a joke... which is why it's a comment.

Comment: Smooth skin in anime always shiny

Comment: Most of these boob images are shiny: https://www.google.com/search?q=anime+boobs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=8EEKVa7qCcinNoGggogF&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAg&biw=1111&bih=770

Comment: she is fightin in the colossuem in that pic, so smooth skin + covered in sweat = shining :)

Comment: Probably related to this question http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/19540/6166

Comment: This'll forever be on top of my stupid questions list..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This picture shows Rebecca fighting in the [Corrida Colosseum](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Corrida_Colosseum) in  [Dressrosa](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Dressrosa) at the Mera Mera no Mi Tournament.

I the One Piece Wiki abpout [Rebecca](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Rebecca) it's said:

> She is a fair-skinned, slender, curvaceous and very well endowed young girl

So we can assume that Rebecca has a very smooth skin. 
Since fighting is very sweat-inducing, we can say that her body is covered in sweat.

Sweat + smooth skin = shiny skin in the right viewing angle

Comment: If you look at how anime skin is colored, most of the time it seems like oil coated rubber (shiny and polished). Just go and use it as an excuse for watching boob animes, you will find tons of shiny round flesh just like the one in OP picture.